# CSS - :hover is slow/laggy in IE7

Tags: html, css, hover, performance, lag

This is really strange. I've got this site where I have a list menu with a simple :hover effect on each item in the menu.

http://w3box.com/mat/

In Firefox it works just fine. But i IE7 atleast there's a lag. I haven't tested it in IE8 but my guess is that it's there as well.

Now, I've been trying out veriations to the code to see what might cause the issue. And I've seen alot of posts about similar scenarios. But none of them seemed to apply to my case.

So just now I noticed that in my css stylesheet, I've got this:

```
li:hover {
background-image: url(img/TopLine.png); 
Height:29px;
```

}

Strange enough, if I remove the height specifications, there is no lag! What could be causing this? Could it be layers of padding and margins to the parent li class? Or the parent class above that one?

This is the code of these items. The rest of the css you can under /main.css of the site

```
#header {
padding-right:7%;
height: 57px;
background-image:url(img/TopLine.png); }

.header a {
font-family:georgia;
font-size:22px;
color:#ebebeb;
text-decoration:none; }

.header li {
float:right;
list-style: none;
margin-top:10px;
padding-top:18px;   
padding-left: 23px;
padding-right: 23px;
height:23px; }

li:hover {
background-image: url(img/TopLine.png); 
Height:29px; }
```

Any ideas on how I can improve this?

Comment: You Norwegians seem to have a *boring* cuisine! ;)

Comment: I'll put my money on the `<canvas>` you've got there. Does it work when you remove the custom fonts?

Comment: But the phenomenon is really, really odd, I get a strong lag on IE 7, and a slight one on IE8. The only culprit that I can think of is the cufon'ed text. Can you try removing that just to see whether anything changes? (Edit: ah, Kobi already said it.)

Comment: Why is `height` capitalized in your hover rule?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes, meatballs are all we eat in Norway :) Anyway, I removed the Cufon script. Did it improve? I've only got IE8 at home at I think it improved a bit. But the thing is, I did testing with Cufon alot prior to this happening. And there was no such error. It was only until I started repositioning everything that this happened.

Comment: The 'Height' was just a typo. Fixed it and it didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: @Kenny, I somehow wasn't notified about your reply. You have moved on and introduced a completely different effect, right? Just checking, because I am now getting a different menu.

Comment: Yes, this is correct :) I'm trying to add a Lavalamp-menu instead. Still trying to work out the positioning correctly. I wanted to do that from the beginning anyway. Also, I've replaced Cufon as well and it seems alot smoother now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really getting any lag. The first time there is a slight delay though - this is most likely because the background image is loading.

You'd be better off setting a background on the list item proper then changing the background position on hover. (There are plenty of questions on SO about this.)

Comment: That's odd @DisgruntledGoat, I am getting a noticeable lag in IE7 even on a quite powerful machine - it's in IEtester, though. Did you try with a "real" IE7?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about setting a background on the list item? Could you elaborate? Would it mean not using :hover. 
Btw, I tried setting the :hover on both 'a:hover" and '.header:hover' etc and the lag happens anyway. It's very strange. But I don't know why it only seems to happen when I set it's height though. Perhaps I need to reposition the entire menu.

Comment: @Pekka: no I'm just using compatibility mode.

Comment: @Kenny: what I mean about the background is that if you set a background image on hover, the first time you hover it loads the image then, not beforehand, hence a delay. You can combine two backgrounds into one image then on hover change the position. Look up "CSS sprites" for more information.

Comment: @DigruntledGoat: But it's the same 1 pixel background image every time, isn't it? It shouldn't be loaded on every hover, should it? It has no "no-cache" headers or anything, I already checked that yesterday.

Comment: I have changed alot of things now. I tried using FontFace instead, incorporating the font in a CSS file instead, which seems to work alot smoother! I've also added a lavalamp-menu effect as well, even though it's not positioned well enough yet. It seems alot smoother now anyway!

Comment: @Pekka: You're right, the lag would only be on the first hover, which seemed to be what I was experiencing. I didn't check the image, I assumed it included the text and everything but looks like custom fonts.